# Add form information in to URL string and submit

Tags: html

I need to get information from my online form added in to my URL string and get it submitted to the dialler.

I have a working URL string that submits data to our dialler ok.

I need to get the first name, last name and phone number from the form submission in to the URL string.

This is how the URL string looks;
http://domain.com/scripts/api.php?user=admin&pass=password&function=add_lead&source=MobileOp&***phone_number=07000000000***&phone_code=44&list_id=3002&***first_name=NAME***&***last_name=SURNAME***&rank=99&campaign_id=campaign&callback=Y&callback_datetime=NOW

This is the form I have;

```
<form id="contact_form" method="post" action="">
<div class="contactform">
<fieldset class="large-12 columns">
<div class="required">
<label>Your First Name:*</label>
<input name="first_name" type="text" class="cms_textfield" id="first_name" value="" size="25" maxlength="80"  required="required" />
</div>
<div class="required">
<label>You Last Name:*</label>
<input name="last_name" type="text" class="cms_textfield" id="last_name" value="" size="25" maxlength="80"  required="required" />
</div>
<div class="required">
<label>Phone Number:*</label>
<input name="phone_number" type:"number" id="phone_number" size="25" maxlength="11" required="required"></input>
</div>
</fieldset>
<p class="right"><strong>Call us now on <a href="tel:01656837180">01656 837180</a></strong></p>
<div class="submit"><input type="submit" value="Submit" class="button small radius"></div>

</div>
</form>
```

I am struggling to get anywhere with this. I have a basic knowledge of PHP.

Comment: Ust the get method instead of post and in the action put the url you want to send the form to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change your form to `method="GET"` and the action to your url `action="http://domain.com/scripts/api.php"` it will include it in the URL string.  That said, showing a user's password as a query string variable is probably a bad idea in the long run.

Instead, you can process the input from the form in PHP by referring to the $_POST array in your code.  For example, to get the first name you'd just use `$_POST['first_name']`

Comment: Would i use the php code on the same page?

I have basic knowledge of PHP. Where would put the     $_POST['first_name']?

I'm a bit confused on where to put the rest of the string - user=admin&pass=password&function=add_lead&source=MobileOp&phone_number=07000000000&phone_code=44&list_id=3002&first_name=NAME&last_name=SURNAME&rank=99&campaign_id=campaign&callback=Y&callback_datetime=NOW

Thanks for your response.

Comment: I haven't got access to the api.php file.

How would get round this?

thanks

Comment: Aah, if it's not your api.php file then you'll just have to do whatever they told you to, which may be using the query string/get parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
<form id="contact_form" method="post" action="">
```

to

```
<form id="contact_form" method="GET" action="">
```

(notice the method 'GET'). GET sends form variables through the URL.

Comment: What would I put in the action?

I'm a bit confused where I put the URL in the form for the form to know where to put the information?

Thanks for your response

Comment: You don't actually need to put anything in the action theoretically. A blank action would submit the form to the current URL.

Comment: If you're using Chrome or Firefox, use the Inspector and view the Network tab to see how your form fields are submitted. Look Under "Query String Parameters".

Answer (score 0):

You can use PHP for this.

if you have an input field of name attribue 'first_name', It'll be stored in the variable $_POST['first_name'] in case of POST as method and $_GET['first_name'] in case of GET method

If you have a url

`http://domain.com/scripts/api.php?user=admin&pass=password&function=add_lead&source=MobileOp&phone_number=07000000000&phone_code=44&list_id=3002&first_name=NAME&last_name=SURNAME&rank=99&campaign_id=campaign&callback=Y&callback_datetime=NOW`,

notice the x=y pattern repeating in it, like user=admin. Here, the first element, x becomes the key to tha PHP array and the second becomes the value.

Comment: Would I need to use a new PHP page for this?

Sorry but I'm pretty new to all coding and only have a basic knowledge of PHP. Thanks

Comment: Some server side language is needed, PHP is preferred because it's powerful and simple, especially if you know C

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function. on your submission page

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            function iter() {
                var str = "";
                $("#contact_form .contactform .required :input").each(function () {           // Iterate over inputs
                    if ($(this).attr('id')) {
                        str += $(this).attr('id') + "=" + $(this).val() + "&";  // Add each to features object
                    }
                });
                str = str.substring(0, str.length - 1);
                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "http://domain.com/scripts/api.php",
                    data: str,
                    async: true,
                    error: function (error) {
                    },
                    success: function (data) {
                    }
                });
            }
        </script>
```

just attach it to the submit button as shown below

```
$("#contact_form .submit").on("click", function () {
      iter();
      return false;
});
```

Comment: I dont have access to the api.php file. my submission page is on a different domain to the URL i need the form to go in to.

How do I overcome this?